# Image flickers on first hover with transform:scale (in Firefox only)

Tags: css

EDIT: Seems the problem is really a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225934).

The effect should simply **zoom the image**, but it **flickers on first hover in FF** (to reproduce use ctrl+F5). Tested with latest FF (45.0.1). In Chrome and IE10 there is no problem.

So it's either a bug in FF, or I am not doing everything correctly. Either way, I would like to know how to fix this.

BTW: I wanted to simply use a **jsfiddle** or **codepen** link, but there I **could not reproduce** the behavior with exactly the same code. (EDIT: But using this code in an HTML file directly makes it reproducible.)

CSS

```
.image-box {   
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.image-box .zoom {  
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.image-box .zoom ~ img {  
    position: absolute;  
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    max-width: 100%;

    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
}

.image-box:hover .zoom ~ img {  
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.3);
    transform:scale(1.3);    
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width: 221px; height: 147px;" class="image-box">
    <div style="width: 221px; height: 147px;" class="zoom"></div>
    <img src="http://media.moddb.com/images/mods/1/22/21735/grizzly3-300x200.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem using the code you provided, then that indicates the problem is somewhere else, doesn't it?

Comment: No. If you create an html file locally and use this exact code, you can reproduce it. Just using jsfidlle, thus having the code in an iframe (or what the difference is) means you cannot reproduce it.

Comment: **Fixed** with `width: 100%` instead of `max-width: 100%`

Comment: _ps: why the inner div (the one with 'zoom' class)? seems to be totally unecessary. Of course if you remove it you would need to update your CSS selectors._

Comment: @freestock.tk This was extracted from a much bigger piece of code, where there is also some text mixed in, but didn't want to change it too much.

Comment: @freestock.tk using `width: 100%` makes it better, but it still flickers sometimes, if you give it more time before you hover. Also, it's easier to reproduce with relative image url, rather than an absolute one. Very strange.

Comment: @Lodovik You might want to change `transition: all .5s;` to `transition: transform .5s;`, as that is the one you change ... this caused issues in another post here (which I can't find right now) so it might do good for you too

Comment: I can confirm ive had this issue.  The flicker wasnt happening on FF v 45.0 (OSX) but is happening on 45.01 (OSX)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug and I didn't find any good fix for now but if you can load images which are a little bit narrower than the container `transition` seems to work as expected.